# Firebird efetuar reset automatico em Generator

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, firebird

Ambiente : servidor linux rodando *FirebirdCS 2.5 SuperClassic* ; aplicação desktop *Delphi 7* *DBExpress*; centena de máquinas consumindo.

Caros amigos,

No banco de dados existe uma tabela de pedidos onde parte da **PK** desta tabela é incrementada por um `Generator` chamado pela aplicação "`SELECT GEN_ID...`" antes da gravação do `insert`.

Observei que na chamada ao `Generator`, quer tenha sido feito `Commit`, `Rollback` ou nada o `Generator` sempre incrementa.

O problema é que preciso fazer com que esse `generator` tenha um limite de incremento e chegado nesse limite ele reinicie a contagem.

Como o `Generator` não tem um evento que eu pudesse implementar uma *Trigger*, pensei em:

Criar uma `Stored Procedure`; a aplicação passa a fazer a consulta a essa `Stored Procedure` dentro de um contexto controlado de transação ( ReadCommitted ) que realizaria o `SELECT GEN_ID` e no valor retornado sendo ele o  limite através de uma *AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION* um outro select efetuar o reinicio do `generator`.

Haveria problema de concorrência a essa `Stored Procedure` e seria essa a melhor maneira?

Obrigado desde já a quem puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

O generator nem sempre incrementa +1 ao busca-lo, veja os exemplos:

Aqui vai ser incrementado +1 ao generator

```
SELECT GEN_ID(GENERATOR, 1) AS ID FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Já desta forma abaixo, apenas é retornado o valor atual do generator

```
SELECT GEN_ID(GENERATOR, 0) AS ID FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Acredito que você possa criar uma trigger na própria tabela sua de pedidos e fazer a validação desejada e reiniciar a contagem do mesmo.

**Exemplo - EDITADO**

Não sei ao certo de que forma você faz na sua aplicação, mas darei um outro exemplo e você tenta aplicar, é um outro exemplo utilizando trigger (Não entendo muito de procedures)...

> Obs.: Testei com o Firedac e li em alguns lugares que o DBExpress
>   também funciona com o returning

**1º -** Crie a trigger aplicando as validações que você utiliza na aplicação:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PEDIDO_BI0 FOR PEDIDO
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
begin
  if ((SELECT GEN_ID(COD_PEDIDO, 0) AS ID FROM RDB$DATABASE) = 1000) then
    EXECUTE STATEMENT('SET GENERATOR COD_PEDIDO TO 0');

    new.PE_CODIGO = 'ABC' || (SELECT GEN_ID(COD_PEDIDO, 1) AS ID FROM RDB$DATABASE);
end
```

**2º -** Você disse que utiliza a PK do pedido para formar a PK dos itens do pedido, então tente assim:

```
procedure MetodoInsertPedido;
begin
  {Vai inserir o pedido, sem informar a PK, pois a trigger irá tratá-la e após a inserção o RETURNING da query irá retornar a PK gerada na trigger}
  qryInsert.SQL.CommandText := 'insert into pedido(data, valor) values (current_date, 10.50) returning id'; 
  qryInsert.Open; {Sim use o open}

  {Aqui você pega o valor da PK que a trigger gerou}
  IdPedido = qryInsert.FieldByName('id').AsString;

  [...insert itens do pedido...]
end;
```

**Entendendo**

1º - A trigger irá ser disparada **antes** de acontecer a inserção do pedido na tabela e então você pode tratar sua PK diretamente na trigger, passando para ela os valores que precisa

2º - Ao usar o `returning` e executar o insert usando o `Open()` da query as coisas aconteceram assim:
  • Executa script de insert
  • Dispara a trigger, que gera o id e já seta ele ao registro
  • Após a execução é retornado o id para a query

Você comentou algo sobre concorrência de acessos, com este exemplo que fiz acredito que você só vai ter a concorrência que já existe na hora de inserção dos pedidos.

Comment: Obrigado Matheus pelo retorno. O valor gerado pelo Generator não compõe a PK totalmente, esse ID é composto por XXX999999 onde XXX é alfa numerico e garante a integridade da PK mesmo que o Generator seja reiniciado. A abordagem da aplicação trazer o valor do incremento se deu pois esse ID é necessário após ser gravado para que o mesmo componha a PK da tabela de itens.

Comment: @antoniocarlos Então porque você não verifica se o ID está no limite permitido quando você busca ele e logo em seguida já reinicia ele diretamente pela aplicação? Dei um exemplo na minha resposta de como pegar o valor atual do generator sem incrementa-lo.

Comment: Então eu tentei isso pela aplicação, pensando que o generator ficasse preso no contexto da minha transação e eu pudesse manipular isso, ocorre que fiz um teste colocando outras 5 maquinas virtuais acessando em um prototipo e o que ocorrer é que por exemplo a maquina 1 faz o select, retorna 999 o limite por exemplo ela procede a mudança, mas nesse momento outras maquinas tambem acessaram e para algumas elas os retornos são 1000 , 1001, tambem tentam processar a mudança

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta, veja se te auxilia em algo!

Comment: Ok, vou testar, vou ver se essa versão do DBExpress aceita o returning , obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Se quer limitar em um valor especifico, como no caso em 999999, utilize assim...

```
SELECT MOD(GEN_ID(COD_PEDIDO, 1),999999) AS ID FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Assim não precisas tratar nada na aplicação e nem se preocupar em resetar a sequence/generator, nem controlar transação, muito menos tratar isto em procedure.